# Canvas Script from external file

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple Canvas element in my HTML5 Code and trying to draw in it with a external javascript file.

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id="can1" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>

//script.js:
var can1 = document.getElementById("play");
var can1Context = play.getContext("2d");
can1Context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
can1Context.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

But this is not working, but if the script is in the same file as the Canvas Element, it works. Can somebody explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
<canvas id="play" width="50px" height="50px"></canvas>
<!--        ^^^^ notice the different id -->
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
var can1 = document.getElementById("play");
var can1Context = can1.getContext("2d");
//                ^^^^ use the variable here, not the id!
can1Context.fillStyle="#FF0000";
can1Context.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572) for an explanation.

Comment: the id of his element and the one he tries to select don't even match, we're having bigger troubles than that here I fear...

Comment: @GNi33: I noticed and fixed it already :-) Anyway, thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I changed the IDs for this example. I meant var can1 = document.getElementById("can1");

Comment: @user2237411: Of course you can use any combination of variable name and element id, only you should distinguish them :-)

Comment: Thanks for the link that helped a lot :)